# UITableView Delegate in Sub Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` call **Parent**, and I have a `UIView` subview within **Parent**. I want to add one of two different possible `UIViewControllers`, called **A** and **B**, as subviews of **Parent**. **A** is a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. I set the `datasource` and `delegate` of the `UITableView` in **A** to **A**.

I can then "successfully" add **A** to **Parent**, setting the data for **A** as follows:

```
    AViewController *vc = (AViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A"];
    NSMutableArray *data = [@[@"foo",@"bar",@"baz"] mutableCopy];
    vc.posts = data;
    [self.container addSubview:vc.view];
```

By successful, I mean that I see the tableview with the correct data in the cells. Namely foo, bar, and baz as the rows.

*My Problem:* When I try to scroll the tableview, it crashes. When I try to select a cell, I get the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '-[_UIAppearanceCustomizableClassInfo
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78c64430'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `AViewController` is declared locally in your code above, it is deallocated as soon as that code completes.  So when you touch for scrolling/selection and the delegate/datasource methods are called, the `delegate` and `datasource` point to a completely different object (or none at all).  Hence your crash.

Furthermore, when implementing customer container views you need to implement some code so both parent and child know.  Take a look at "Implementing a Custom Container View Controller" in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html):

```
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self.container addSubview:vc.view];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I believe the `addChildViewController` will also provide a strong reference from the parent to the child (`vc`), thereby preventing it from being deallocated.  So the above code should fix the deallocation problem as well.

Comment: this works! now, is there anything special I have to do if A has a navigationcontroller attached to it?

Comment: If view controller A is embedded in a navigation controller in your storyboard, then you would instantiate the navigation controller itself (eg `UINavigationController *navCtrl = (UINavigationController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Nav"];`) and then use the `topViewController` property to get a reference to vc A (eg. `AViewController *vc = (AViewController *)navCtrl.topViewController;`).  You can then set `data` on vc A, and add `navCtrl.view` to your container view.