# Why does initializing a view controller with nibName not set the new instance as file owner?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit

I am trying to display one view or another view inside the detail view of a master/detail based on a conditional.

These views will contain outlets and elements, so I would like to have view controllers for each that I can play with.

So I created a new `UIViewController` called `AddPhotoViewController`. This is how I add `AddPhotoViewController.xib` inside `DetailViewController`:

```
let photoVC = AddPhotoViewController(nibName: "AddPhotoViewController", bundle: nil)
let photoView = photoVC.view

photoVC.delegate = self

photoView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
photoView.frame = area.bounds
area.addSubview(photoView)
```

The view loads properly in the detail view and looks like this:

[image: The XIB file loading properly in the detail view]

`AddPhotoViewController.xib`'s owner class has been set as well here:

[image]

When I tap the button, though the action is set properly in `AddPhotoViewController` to print a message, Xcode crashes.

Am I doing this correctly? **Is there a more common practice for loading view X or view Y inside a view controller depending on user data?**

Button action:

```
@IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("worked!")
}
```

Button connection:

[image]

Console output:

[image]

Comment: What kind of an error message do you get when the app crashes? What is the code that calls the function that is supposed to print the message?

Comment: I think you have the same problem as in [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28521844/3985749).

Comment: You're right. photoVC falls out of scope outside of that block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the viewController:

```
addChildViewController(PhotoVC)
//and then
PhotoVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```